# How can I write this diffusion creep equation in python?

Tags: python, equation

In the image I wrote the diffusion creep equation with all its variables. I just need to understand how I can transfer this into python.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxcNP.jpg]

I was trying to the first part of the equation but I'm not sure how to include the last part.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/geAlf.png]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what isn't working? I suggest starting with some basic python tutorials. If you are unable to translate this into python, you will not be able to use an answer someone may provide you.

Comment: I included what I tried so far, I guess my main issue is that I don't know how to translate the 'exp' part

Comment: `from math import exp` and then `exp(42)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use exp method in math module

```
import math

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = lambda A, d, m, n, E, P, V, R, T: 2 * pow(A, -1 / n) * pow(d, m / n) * \
                                            math.exp((E + P * V) / (n * R * T))
    print(foo(A=4.5, d=1, m=3, n=1, E=10.0 ** -15, P=1, V=6, R=8.314463, T=1623))
```

Comment: since `exp` value is very large its giving `OverflowError: math range error`

Comment: try to pass smaller value to `exp` method in `math` module

Comment: You missed parenthesis in the denominator. Should be `(n * R * T)`.

Comment: You also shouldn't name `lambda` expressions, they're literally called *anonymous* functions.